# Can we assign integer with negative number to unsigned integer?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    int i=-5;
    unsigned int j=i;
    printf("%d",j);
    getch();
}

O/p
-----
-5

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    int i=-5;
    unsigned int j=i;
    printf("%u",j);
    getch();
}

O/p
===
4255644633
```

Here I am not getting any compilation error .

It is giving -5 when print with the identifier %d and when printing with %u it is printing some garbage value .

The things I want to know  are

1) Why compiler ignores when assigned integer with negative number to unsigned int.

2) How it is converting signed to unsigned ?

Comment: If you turn on warnings, the compiler will warn you that you're assigning a signed to an unsigned. The compiler just copies the number over. So the sign bit ends up being part of the number in the unsigned case. So if you assign a negative number, `n`, to an unsigned, you will get a large number `2^32-|n|` (if it's a 32-bit word) or `2^64-|n|` if it's a 64-bit word.

Comment: What I see confusing is that in two's complement, `-5` should be `4294967291`, not `4255644633`. I checked out in `gcc` and that was indeed the value I got. I don't understand how he gets different value.

Comment: @user3095972: The second code you posted cannot possibly output `4255644633`. You are either posting the wrong code or the wrong output.

Answer (score 3):

Who are "we?"

There's no "garbage value", it's probably just the result of viewing the bits of the signed integer as an unsigned. Typically [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) will result in very large values for many a negative values. Try printing the value in hex to see the pattern more clearly, in decimal they're often hard to decipher.

Comment: Minor note: a value *not* "close to 0" will *also* show a very large value -- at least 2^31 -1, or 2,147,483,648. (On a 32-bit integer system. 64-bit systems will show an even higher value.)

Comment: @Jongware True, I removed that bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply add that the concept of signed or unsigned is something that humans appreciate more than machines.

Assuming a 32-bit machine, your value of -5 is going to be represented internally by the 32-bit value 0xFFFFFFFB (two's complement).

When you insert `printf("%d",j);` into your source code, the compiler couldn't care less whether j is signed or unsigned, it just shoves 0xFFFFFFFB onto the stack and then a pointer to the `"%d"` string. The `printf` function when called looks at the format string, sees the `%d` and knows from that that it has to *interpret* the 0xFFFFFFFB as a *signed* value, hence the reason for it displaying `-5` despite `j` being an unsigned int.

On the other hand, when you write `printf("%u",j);`, the `"%u"` makes `printf` interpret your 0xFFFFFFFB as an *unsigned* value. That value is 2^32 - 5, or 4294967291.

It's the format string passed to `printf` that determines how the value will be interpreted, not the type of the variable `j`.

Comment: Finally someone who understands the topic, and does not make vague statements about "sign bits"!  +1

Comment: On the contrary, the explanation of the first code's behavior given in this answer is just an attempt to pick apart a specific manifestation of undefined behavior. Given the state of modern compiler development (like advanced format error checking and `printf` being a built-in function in GCC, for one example), the explanation might prove to be completely inaccurate. The first code is broken, that's all there is to it.

Comment: The second explanation is incorrect from the point of view of C language. C language defines the behavior of signed-to-unsigned conversion at language level and defines is perfectly well without any need for bringing in any 2's complement bit patterns. Saying that the second case behaves that way simply because the result happens to be `0xFFFFFFFB` is misleading and incorrect. It will only read to more confusion down the road.

Answer (score 1):

There's noting unusual in the possibility to assign a negative value to an unsigned variable. The implicit conversion that happens in such cases is perfectly well defined by C language. The value is brought into the range of the target unsigned type in accordance with the rules of modulo arithmetic. The modulo is equal to `2^N`, where `N` is the number of value bits in the unsigned recipient. This is how it has always been in C.

Printing an `unsigned int` value with `%d` specifier makes no sense. This specifier requires a `signed int` argument. Because of this mismatch, the behavior of your first code  is undefined.

In other words, you got it completely backwards with regards to which value is garbage and which is not.

Your *first* code is essentially "printing garbage value" due to undefined behavior. The fact that it happens to match your original value of `-5` is just a specific manifestation of undefined behavior.

Meanwhile, the *second* code is supposed to print a well-defined proper value. It should be result of conversion of `-5` to `unsigned int` type by modulo `UINT_MAX + 1`. In your case that modulo probably happens to be `2^32 = 4294967296`, which is why you are supposed to see `4294967296 - 5 = 4294967291`.

How you managed to get `4255644633` is not clear. Your `4255644633` is apparently a result of different code, not the one you posted.

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is that `2^32` ain't `4255644638`, it is `4294967295`. I don't know why he's getting that value.

Comment: @Paulo Bu: You are right. I got duped by the post and simply added 5+1 to the output :) Apparently, the OP's output was generated by different code.

Answer (score 0):

You can and you should get a warning (or perhaps failure) depending on the compiler and the settings.

The value you get is due to twos-complement.

Comment: -1 conversion from signed to unsigned follows well defined conversions. These shouldn't give warning and under no circumstances fail compilation.

Comment: @JensGustedt - I did not mentions that it was not well defined. But you can configure VS to fail instead of giving warnings. See #pragma

Answer (score 0):

The output in the second case is not a garbage value...

```
int i=-5;
```

when converted to binary form the Most Significant Bit is assigned '1' as -5 is a negative number..

but when u use %u the binary form is treated as a normal number and the 1 in MSB is treated a part of normal number..